# Reuse common elements in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

in XSD how can I reuse the tag `<indicator>` and its common elements like `<aa>` and `<bb>`, because there are other elements under it on each `Req`.

```
<Req>
 <AReq>
    ...
    <indictator>
       <aa></aa>
       <bb></bb>
       <numero></numero>
    </indicator>
 </AReq>

 <BReq>
    ...
    <indictator>
       <aa></aa>
       <bb></bb>
       <name> </name>
    </indicator>
 </BReq>

 <CReq>
    ...
    <indictator>
       <aa></aa>
       <bb></bb>
       <data> </data>
    </indicator>
 </CReq>
</Req>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways of doing this.

You could give the three `indictator` elements different types that reuse the declarations of `a` and `b`:

```
<xs:element name="AReq">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="indictator">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="a"/>
            <xs:element ref="b"/>
            <xs:element name="numero">
              ...
```

with global element declarations for `a` and `b`.

Or you could go further and define a named model group (`xs:group`) containing `a` and `b`.

Or you could define the types of the three `indictator` elements as three different types all derived by extension from a base type that only includes `a` and `b`.

In all these approaches the key thing to note is that the three `indictator` element have different content models, and therefore need to have separate element declarations (which must necessarily be local declarations).

If you have an XSD 1.1 processor there is another option: you could define the type of `indictator` to allow a choice of `numero`, `name`, or `data`, and define an assertion at the level of the containing element, for example `AReq`, to the effect that it must have a descendant `numero` element: `<xs:assert test="exists(.//numero)"/>`